postfix: fatal: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 53: missing '=' after attribute name: "smtps inet n - - - - smtpd
Using ubuntu 24.04 LTS.
I have verified my cert key are correct.
Also not showing port 465 listening but the firewall rule is there.
main.cf
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 3.6 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 3.6



# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/mailserver.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/mailserver.key
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
# smtp_tls_CApath =  /etc/ssl/certs/
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
smtp_tls_security_level=may


smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache


smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = *****.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, ******.com, localhost.com, , localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all

smtps inet n - - - - smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject_invalid_helo_hostname,reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject_non_fqdn_sender,reject_unknown_sender_domain
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
root@*******:/etc/postfix#


You're using the wrong file to add your listener declarations and such.
Your smtps inet n - - - - smtpd ... section needs to be done in master.cf not main.cf.
Edit / modify the smtps line in /etc/postfix/master.cf instead of /etc/postfix/main.cf and remove these likes from main.cf.
You should then be able to restart your Postfix server.

thank you so much, dont know how i missed that, :(

sudo netstat -tuln | grep 465 still not showing listening.

@Kwilzz and you've restarted Postfix?  You'll need to share the contents of your master.cf and any output from /var/log/mail.log from the restart as an edit.  However, you might want to open a new question because that may be a different issue than the one you had before.  (YOu may also want to accept this one because it got you past the first error set)
